# c++ pointer to member function from a nested class

Tags: c++, pointers, nested

I have a problem with a pointer defined in an nested class 'Outer::Inner' to a member function of the 'Outer' class:

```
class Outer{
//class Inner;
class Inner{
    public:
        Inner(Outer& o){
        }
        int (Outer::*pf)(int);
};

public:
    Outer();
    ~Outer();
    int function(int a);
    Inner* i;
};
Outer::Outer(){
    i = new Inner( *this );
    i->pf= &Outer::function;
    (i->*pf)(2); //problem here!
};
Outer::~Outer(){
    delete i;
};

int Outer::function(int a){
    return 0;
};
```

As you can see I would like to call the function through the pointer of the Inner class but I get an error: 'pf' was not declared in this scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, `pf` is not declared in that scope. It's a member of `i`, accessible as `i->pf`. Presumably, you want to call it on `this`:

```
(this->*(i->pf))(2);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right that solved the problem. I have to admit that I am a bit lost sometimes with all the pointers... Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions.

1: (pointer to non-member function)

```
class Outer{
class Inner{
    public:
        Inner(Outer& o){
        }
        int (*pf)(int);
};
public:
    Outer();
    ~Outer();
    static int function(int a);
    Inner* i;
};
Outer::Outer(){
    i = new Inner( *this );
    i->pf= &Outer::function;
    int j = (*(i->pf))(2); // now OK
};
```

2: (pointer to member function, has to be called on some instance's)

```
class Outer{
class Inner{
    public:
        Inner(Outer& o){
        }
        int (Outer::*pf)(int);
};
public:
    Outer();
    ~Outer();
    int function(int a);
    Inner* i;
};
Outer::Outer(){
    i = new Inner( *this );
    i->pf= &Outer::function;
    int j = (this->*(i->pf))(2); // now OK
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function "on" some `Outer` object, as it's a pointer to a *member* function.

Looking at your code, maybe you need this

```
//-----------------vvv   <- argument
   (this->*(i->pf))(2);
//-^--------------^  <- these are important and they say something like
// "execute function `*(i->pf)` on `this` object"
```